# Qual è il significato di "leva" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Mi mostravi ad esempio qualche compagno di scuola. Spigliato fino alla 
>   sfrontatezza riusciva ad eccellere anche quando non studiava per l’abilità ad esaltare le sue cognizioni. Ma io crescevo senza modelli capaci di suscitarmi emulazioni. Ci sono poveri per i quali il ricco non è un’aspirazione. Ci sono poveri, in sostanze e in spirito, renitenti alla **leva**.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "leva" in parecchi dizionari e ho letto le differenti accezioni. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa significhi "leva" nel brano sopra citato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: In questo caso _"renitente"_ aiuta più di _leva_... Se vuoi approfondire un po' il termine e le conseguenze c'è una [risorsa sul sito della Treccani datata 1936](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/renitenza-alla-leva_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/)... A seconda del periodo (soprattutto se durante la guerra) le pene sono state ovviamente diverse...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La leva era (il realtà è ancora perché è soltanto sospesa) l’obbligo di prestare servizio militare della durata di 10 mesi per tutti i giovani maschi abili una volta raggiunti i 18 anni.

Renitente alla leva veniva considerato chi non si presentava alla chiamata, incorrendo in un reato penale.

Nel brano da te citato il senso mi pare figurato come a dire che i poveri in sostanze e in spirito neanche provavano ad avere aspirazioni o desideri.

Comment: Solo per completare: la _chiamata di leva_ in Italia ha previsto periodi di diversa durata, andata riducendosi nel tempo fino alla attuale sospensione. A secoda della scelta fatta (quando possibile) anche nell'ultimo periodo poteva durare fino a 18 mesi (se allievo ufficiale). Nell'ultimo periodo i chiamati alla leva potevano fare obiezione di  coscienza ed optare per il servizio civile, sempre che si fosse rientrati nei numeri stabiliti anno per anno...