# Che cosa sono le "leve forzate"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Molti divisero meco tale vita, e da essi e ad essi fui
>   volta a volta dalle circostanze separato e riunito, ma non mi rimase, da ultimo, che un compagno, insieme al quale ci spingemmo
>   nel cuore d'una regione montagnosa relativamente prossima a
>   quanto si dice il mondo civile, eppure estremamente selvaggia.
>   Ivi, un certo giorno dell'autunno inoltrato, decidemmo, contrastando momentaneamente i nostri personali interessi, di separarci, ma soltanto fino alla notte. Ci lasciammo dunque nel fitto d'un bosco (poiché era segnalato un forte nucleo d'armati che, sulle più basse pendici, procedevano a una delle solite **leve forzate**),
>   dopo aver stabilito il punto di ritrovo. Ma la nostra riveduta non
>   ebbe mai luogo.

La scena ha luogo durante la seconda guerra mondiale.

La mia domanda è sul significato di queste "leve forzate" che appaiono nel passaggio precedente. Si tratta chiaramente di un senso militare, ma quello della "chiamata alle armi dei cittadini" che appare nei dizionari non mi sembra adatto al contesto del brano. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono le "leve forzate" nel testo sopra citato?

Comment: La “leva” è la stessa di [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/qual-%C3%A8-il-significato-di-leva-in-questo-contesto), anche se in questo caso non è una leva formale svolta da un'autorità statale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La ***leva forzata*** era il reclutamento coatto (o coscrizione obbligatoria) di tutti gli uomini che potevano combattere e spesso avveniva anche in luoghi appena conquistati.

In questi [Scritti (1935-1945) di Eugenio Curiel](https://books.google.it/books?id=pyUADQAAQBAJ&pg=PT646&lpg=PT646&dq=leve%20forzate&source=bl&ots=3u8V9EuN3r&sig=Bmex2w3Y2A_9fSMQfKVdeG8FIwc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwias-aAhv3ZAhWBzKQKHYYQB54Q6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=leve%20forzate&f=false) si può leggere:

> Il Fronte della Gioventù può affermare di aver dato un contributo
>   essenziale alla resistenza delle masse giovanili contro le ***leve
>   forzate*** della "repubblica", un contributo essenziale al rafforzamento
>   delle file partigiane.

E ancora in questa [Gazzetta universale del 1777](https://books.google.it/books?id=EXIpAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=leve%20forzate&source=bl&ots=mBL1loXoB4&sig=R88Zvp4LVP9_P1aBRmdBxVkcmSM&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwias-aAhv3ZAhWBzKQKHYYQB54Q6AEINjAG#v=onepage&q=leve%20forzate&f=false) si legge:

> Si sono finora continuate le indicate ***leve forzate*** in questo Regno, e
>   non si son risparmiati né i giovani maritati, né quegli che si erano
>   iniziati a' primi ordini sacri. Molti per sottrarsi dal servire nell'Armata,
>   si son ritirati nelle montagne, e né boschi.